# Using LogonUser for impersonation but still getting UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I am using dwLogonType = 9 (LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS) and dwLogonProvider = 3 (LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50)

I am currently trying to impersonate USER_B while being logged on as USER_A. The purpose of the impersonation is to access a resource on a network share (which, just in case, is something like `\\host_b\folder$\subfolder_1\subfolder_2\file_b.JPG` )

USER_A does not have rights to write to `file_b.JPG`.
USER_B does (I've tested by logging to host_b using USER_B credentials).

However, after impersonating USER_B, when `file_b.JPG` should be written I'm greeted with a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` exception.

I don't know what could be the issue, specially when in other cases the impersonation has worked flawlessly.

The code I'm using to impersonate is the following, by creating a new instance of `Impersonator`

```
namespace Util.Impersonation
{

    public class Impersonator : IDisposable
    {

        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Impersonator));

        
        public Impersonator(
            string userName,
            string domainName,
            string password)
        {
            ImpersonateValidUser(userName, domainName, password);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UndoImpersonation();
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int LogonUser(
            string lpszUserName,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        private void ImpersonateValidUser(
            string userName,
            string domain,
            string password)
        {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = null;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            logger.Info($"Trying to impersonate {userName}@{domain}.");
            try
            {
                if (RevertToSelf())
                {
                    if (LogonUser(userName,
                                  domain,
                                  password,
                                  Settings.Impersonation_dwLogonType,
                                  Settings.Impersonation_dwLogonProvider,
                                  ref token) != 0)
                    {
                        if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                        {
                            tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                            impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();

                            logger.Info($"Succesfully impersonating {userName}@{domain}.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LogErrorAndThrow();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LogErrorAndThrow();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    LogErrorAndThrow();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(token);
                }

                if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                }
            }
        }

        private void LogErrorAndThrow()
        {
            var exception = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            logger.ErrorFormat("There was a problem during impersonation: {0}", exception);
            throw exception;
        }

        private void UndoImpersonation()
        {
            if (impersonationContext != null)
            {
                logger.Info($"Trying to undo impersonation.");
                impersonationContext.Undo();
                logger.Info($"Succesfully undo impersonation.");
            }
        }

        private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you read and understand what `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` do ? this is clone current token, the *userName* and *password* ignored - you can use any not empty strings here. and are your user have `SeImpersonatePrivilege` ?

Comment: The first thing to do is look in the security log on the remote server to see why it thinks it rejected the connection.  (There won't always be anything there, but if there is it may be a useful clue.)  You should probably also try LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT instead of LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50.  And of course make sure the domain, username and password are actually valid on the remote system.